# Why can't we gzip more than 1 file using 7zip

Tags: zip, compression, gzip

Recently I noticed that if I try to compress more than 1 file using 7zip, gzip format is not present in the Archive Format-List. Can anyone explain why?

Can't we have more than 1 file in gzip?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXrc4.png)

I'm using 7-Zip v9.20. I also tried with v16. But same there/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't have more than one file in the gzip format.

Instead you would use tar *followed* by gzip. tar converts a set of directories and files into a stream of bytes, which is then compressed by gzip. You have probably already seen these files, with the suffix .tar.gz.

Comment: Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because you can't have more than one file in the gzip format. That is the definition of the format. Period.