# Compress gzip All file in the folder

Tags: go, compression, gzip, archive

I use `compress/gzip` library to compress files in folder with `.gz` format.

I encountered the following trouble:

My `storages` folder has the structure below:

- first.txt (1MB)
- second.txt (2MB)

But after I used a decompression software (for example, app keka macos), I only received back a single file with name is `first.txt` the total capacity of the two files `3MB`.

I want `output.gz` after decompression to receive `2 files` before compression.

I use the following code to compress those files into an `output.gz` file.

Link code: https://go.dev/play/p/_K3aBoqgqKX

```
package services

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func compress() {
    currentDirectory, _ := os.Getwd()

    sourceFolder := currentDirectory + "/storages"

    outputFilename := currentDirectory + "/storages/" + "output.gz"

    outputFile, err := os.Create(outputFilename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer outputFile.Close()

    gzipWriter, _ := gzip.NewWriterLevel(outputFile, gzip.BestCompression)
    defer gzipWriter.Close()

    err = filepath.Walk(sourceFolder, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() || filepath.Ext(path) == ".gz" || filepath.Ext(path) == ".DS_Store" {
            return nil
        }

        sourceFile, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }
        defer sourceFile.Close()

        gzipWriter.Name = info.Name()

        _, err = io.Copy(gzipWriter, sourceFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        }

        fmt.Printf("Compress %s to %s\n", path, outputFilename)
        return nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}

func main() {
    compress()
}
```

Comment: gzip is one file by design. You have to tar the files befor gziping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we gzip more than 1 file using 7zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375631/why-cant-we-gzip-more-than-1-file-using-7zip)

Comment: When I use Nodejs library https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver, I can compress multiple files into 1 .gz file. Can you tell me where I am lacking in knowledge?

and if i use tar before gzip is there any way my file name is output.gz instead of output.tar.gz?

Thank

Comment: Go provides separate packages for tar an gzip because the functionality is separate (although frequently used together).   Use the writer returned from gzip.NewWriterLevel as the argument to [tar.NewWriter](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/tar#NewWriter).  The packages place no restriction the file extension used when creating the file.  You can name the file output.gz if that's what you want.

Comment: The Node thing mixes stuff up. As usual.

Comment: «When I use Nodejs library…». In the Unix world, where both `gzip` and `tar` have originated, there was the distinction between _archivers_ and _compressors_ since the beginning: TAR is an archiver: it creates a single file which contains multiple source files, and GZIP compresses a single file (or an arbitrary data stream, even). So to have "multiple files gzipped into one", you have to TAR them first and then GZIP the result. There exist formats and program dealing with them which combine both properties–ZIP and RAR and 7zip are popular examples.

Comment: Why the njs package you're referring to opted to dumb thing down–I do not know. As you can see, as usually in such cases, an arguable ease of use turned out to bite you in the neck later.